# COOKIES PHP No se detectan hasta que no actualizo la página

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

Tengo un código que hace 3 cosas:

- Si no hay una cookie llamada "ip", se crea uno y se le añade la IP del visitante
- Se comprueba que se ha creado la cookie (para comprobar si las cookies están habilitadas)
- Se comprueba que la IP de la cookie es la del visitante (para futuras visitas).

El problema es que en la primera visita, me detecta que no se ha creado la cookie, cuando sí se ha creado, y también me detecta que no son las mismas, cuando si lo son.

Luego, cuando recargo, ya sí me dice que está creada y sí coinciden.

Este es el código y está ordenado de esta forma:

```
// ESTABLECER COOKIES
if(!isset($_COOKIE["ip"])) {
    setcookie("ip", $user_ip, time() + 604800, "/");
}


// COMPROBAR COOKIES
if(isset($_COOKIE["ip"])) {
    $check_cookies = true;
}


// COMPROBAR SI ES LA MISMA IP
if ($_COOKIE["ip"] == $user_ip) {
    $check_sameIP = true;
}
```

Primera visita:

```
check_cookies: bool(false) 
check_sameIP: bool(false)
```

Segunda visita:

```
check_cookies: bool(true) 
check_sameIP: bool(true)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No se puede usar `isset()` después de haber creado la Cookie con `setcookie()` ya que el array asociativo `$_COOKIES` se actualizará tras recargar la página.
Ese es el funcionamiento correcto, hasta que no se recargue la página no se actualizan las cookies.